How to analysis CNN model?
Hellow all,
What is Interpretability analysis of CNN model?
What is the computational complexity of the CNN model?
AlexNet model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
     Conv2D(96, kernel_size=(11,11), strides= 4,
                    padding= 'valid', activation= 'relu',
                    input_shape=(227, 227, 3),
                    kernel_initializer= 'he_normal'),
     MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides= (2,2),
                          padding= 'valid', data_format= None),

    Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(5,5), strides= 1,
                    padding= 'same', activation= 'relu',
                    kernel_initializer= 'he_normal'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides= (2,2),
                          padding= 'valid', data_format= None), 

    Conv2D(384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides= 1,
                    padding= 'same', activation= 'relu',
                    kernel_initializer= 'he_normal'),

    Conv2D(384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides= 1,
                    padding= 'same', activation= 'relu',
                    kernel_initializer= 'he_normal'),

    Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides= 1,
                    padding= 'same', activation= 'relu',
                    kernel_initializer= 'he_normal'),

    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides= (2,2),
                          padding= 'valid', data_format= None),
    
    Flatten(),
    Dense(4096, activation= 'relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(4096, activation= 'relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(num_classes, activation= 'softmax')

])
